# Zoom & crop an image and draw an svg-square on top (in angular)

Tags: css, angular, svg

"A stackblitz is worth a thousand words": https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zoom-crop-marker

Basically what I'm trying to do is to have a square drawn above a certain position in an image (`<img>`), and have that dynamically adjust to the image while being zoomed in / out and cropped. The stackblitz link has 3 views, the basic view which is a plain image, a zoomable view (which I got working as well) and a view where the imaged is "zoomed in and cropped" while being zoomable - This is where I need your help.

Should I crop using object-fit in some way? Is it better if I use a canvas to handle this? I've been at this for a whole day I and I feel my css knowledge is too limited to pull this of.

**Bonus question**: How would I go about to have the zoom-in zoom-out buttons add/remove one image per row using only css flex-box? (ie: not statically adding x pixles in height and width, but rather increase or decrease the size of each image so that another image is removed or added (per row) while always filling up all the available space)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve it myself. stackblitz updated with a working solution.